# Add new option in runtime to already registered HttpClient service

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, dependency-injection

In the startup of application I regiseter a new HttpClient named AmadeusSearchClient.

```
services.AddHttpClient<AmadeusSearchClient>(options =>
    {
        options.BaseAddress = new Uri(configuration.GetSection("AmadeusApi:BaseAddress").Value);
        options.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, int.Parse(configuration["AmadeusAccessToken:Timeout"]));
    });
    return services;
```

I'm receiving Amadeus access token using my other HttpClient called AmadeusAccessTokenClient, also registered in DI.

```
services.AddHttpClient<AmadeusAccessTokenClient>(options =>
    {
        options.BaseAddress = new Uri(configuration.GetSection("AmadeusApi:BaseAddress").Value);
        options.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, int.Parse(configuration["AmadeusAccessToken:Timeout"]));
    });
    return services;
```

To properly use AmadeusSearchClient, I need to add access token in the header of my request.

```
cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

        var message = new HttpRequestMessage(
            HttpMethod.Get,
            "v1/travel/analytics/air-traffic/busiest-period?cityCode=BOS&period=2017");

        _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {_token.Get()}");

        var response = await _httpClient.SendAsync(message, cancellationToken);

        var res = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

As you can see, in every request I have to add `_httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {_token.Get()}");`
DefaultRequestHeader manually. Is there any way to update the options of already registered AmadeusSearchClient when my application receives access token using AmadeusAccessTokenClient service?

Comment: No, because the service collection is read-only after start-up, and `HttpClient`s generated by the `HttpClientFactory` are transient i.e. a new instance is created each time. What problems are you having with your current approach?

Answer (score 2):

Old question, but this still might be usefull to someone.

I believe you can make use of outgoing request middleware to achieve this.

You need to create a handler that inherits from DelegatingHandler and override the SendAsync methed.

```
public class AddHeaderHandler: DelegatingHandler
{
  protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
    HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
  {
    request.Headers.Add("CUSTOM-HEADER","CUSTOM HEADER VALUE");
    return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
  }

}
```

Then you can register like this:

```
service.AddTransient<HeaderHandler>()
.AddHttpClient<MyHttpClient>()
.AddHttpMessageHandler<HeaderHandler>();
```

Hope this helps:
[Outgoing request middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-7.0#outgoing-request-middleware;)